# React Component not rendering until all images are loaded - Ruby on Rails and React on Rails

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, react-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails project with the gem react_on_rails. I'm having trouble in a specific situation:

If I have image tag referencing an url that its taking a long time to load. The React Component wont show up on the screen until its done or I click on cancel loading button on the browser.

I tried to use

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  ReactOnRails.reactOnRailsPageLoaded();
});
```

And it makes the component show up, however the following warning appears once the page loads:

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before. Instead, call root.render() on the existing root instead if you want to update it.
```

But more worrying is that if I start to edit the content on my React Component before the page finishes loading, once it does, it will erase the content, and if in development mode it will show a big alert on the screen with the error:

```
Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

```
There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
```

I am not using turbo links on this project. I have stimulus in a few components, and my application.js is as follow:

```
import Rails from '@rails/ujs'
import * as ActiveStorage from '@rails/activestorage'

ActiveStorage.start()
Rails.start();

import $ from 'jquery'
import toastr from 'toastr'
import ReactOnRails from 'react-on-rails';
import { RelacionamentoAutocomplete } from '../components/relacionamento-autocomplete';
import { FormRelatorioModeloOpcao } from '../components/form-relatorio-modelo-opcao';
import { BotaoUploadRelatorio } from '../components/botao-upload-relatorio';

global.$ = $
global.jQuery = $
global.toastr = toastr
global.Rails = Rails

import "controllers"

//tried this just to see if it changed something
ReactOnRails.setOptions({
  turbo: false,
  traceTurbolinks: false
})

ReactOnRails.register({
  RelacionamentoAutocomplete,
  FormRelatorioModeloOpcao,
  BotaoUploadRelatorio
});

import "../view-components";

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  ReactOnRails.reactOnRailsPageLoaded();
});
```

My javascript is being loaded through:

```
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', defer: false %>
```

Here is a print of the errors:

[image: Error]

[image: Erro2]

Any help is appreciated. Don't know what else to do. It's my understanding that the components should load once the DOM has loaded with the local assets.

### Environment

1. Ruby version: 3.2.2
2. Rails version: 7.0.4.3
3. Shakapacker version:  7.0.2
4. React on Rails version: 13.4.0

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode - don't put pictures of your errors in the question -- add as text